# What is Firebase's cross-domain policy?

Tags: cross-domain, cors, firebase, cross-domain-policy, firebase-security

How does Firebase handle cross origin issues, and what are the underlying security concerns and how are they handled?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### Ways to Connect

There are multiple ways to communicate with the Firebase servers, and these include:

- **Firebase Client** - One of the officially-supported client libraries, currently including JavaScript (both for Web and Node.js), ObjC (iOS and Mac OS-X), and JVM (Android and Java).
- **REST API** - Accessible via `https://<your-firebase>.firebaseio.com`.

#### CORS Policy

Firebase uses a fully-permissive cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) policy, meaning that you can make requests to the Firebase servers from any origin. This is possible because Firebase does **not** use cookies or traditional sessions to govern which requests are authorized and which are not.

#### Cross-Domain Policy File (Flash)

Similarly, Firebase uses a fully-permissive cross-domain policy file, requiring only that requests be made over SSL. See the policy file at https://demo.firebaseio-demo.com/crossdomain.xml.

#### Security Overview

Firebase relies upon a [flexible authentication system](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/authentication.html) and [expression-based rules language](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/security-rules.html) to govern which requests are authorized and which are not.

In order for a request to be authorized, the request must include a [Firebase Authentication Token](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/custom-login.html), which is a way of securely sharing data between your server (or authentication provider, if using [Firebase Simple Login](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/simple-login-overview.html)), and the operation (and corresponding data) must pass the developer-defined security rules.

Firebase is accessible from anywhere via the client libraries or REST API, and enables you to build a fully-secure application using only client-side code. Get started with Firebase authentication by heading to the [Quickstart Guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security-quickstart.html).