# Firebase not adding CORS headers to REST requests

Tags: firebase

Is there a way to enable CORS for REST endpoints, as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19486655/what-is-firebases-cross-domain-policy) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10710635/how-does-firebase-handle-cross-origin-issues)? It looks like Firebase no longer adds them by default. It would be helpful for apps that don't need realtime connectivity or cant use websockets.

Here's a REST request to Firebase. If you check the response, there are no cors headers:
https://samplechat.firebaseio-demo.com/users/jack/name.json

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Found the issue.

*All* the REST endpoints need to end in '.json', including put and post requests. That triggers Firebase to set the cross-origin headers to the origin on the request. By not adding the '.json' to the end of my POST request, the origin headers were not added so it looked like a CORS issue.

The example doesn't have a CORS header, so it looks like Firebase must add them only when needed.

Comment: Note that without `.json`, Firebase tries to load the developer console available at `<your-project>.firebaseio.com`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using REST instead of the JS SDK?

Comment: My app is primarily built for offline use, with only periodic syncs to the backend. I'd rather handle the offline state myself than set up websockets that constantly try to reconnect. I keep a parallel db in indexeddb where I keep track of offline modifications and then merge with online updates when the user goes back online.