# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource | Firebase Cloud Firestore - Java - Ionic

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, jax-rs, java-ee-8

I'm developing an application and I'm using Ionic (Angular) for client side, java (JAX-RS) as backend and Firebase Cloud Firestore for persistence. Maybe this stack is weird but I'm new in create real applications and Firebase caughy my attention.

I want to save data in Firebase Cloud Firestore using Ionic with an REST API, I can do this with tools like postman, but i can't with Ionic, I'm getting an error *No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource*. You will say to me that configure my server to allow requests but I do this already, I test my REST API without including the part of saving data in Firebase Cloud Firestore, and this work perfectly, I don't get that error. The problem only spends when I call a Firebase method.

**Server Configuration**

I add the following Java Class

```
package api;

public class RestCorsFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        //enter code here
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
        resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");

        chain.doFilter(request, resp);

    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {

    }

}
```

And then, I add this fragment in `web.xml`

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>RestCorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>api.RestCorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>RestCorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

My application path:

```
@ApplicationPath("/api")
```

Comment: Please share how your are configuring that, we need to see you actual code/configuration in order to point you where the error is. That being said I found this [community answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34341196/12857703) that might have something to do with the problem you are facing.

Comment: Is the Servlet Filter being called?

Comment: I think when I added the code at web.xml is calling the filter class.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this error because every exception caused in the java application was showed in browser's console as a CORS error. The solution was look at the application log to catch and deal with the exception generated by the application.

Comment: Please provide a detailed explanation to your answer, in order for the next user to understand your answer better.