# Select data from firebase via id gives me a CORS error

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm deleting data from my firebase db with **fetch** but I can't figure out how to point to an exact ID.

```
const deleteHandler = async (id) => {
console.log(id);
await fetch(
  `https://react-task-tracker-8e519-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/tasks.json/${id}`,
  {
    method: "DELETE",
  }
);
```

I tried it this way, but it gives me a **CORS** error.
I'm also displaying data from this db, that works fine.

UPDATE: I also want to say that when i console.log the id it gives me the correct one.

Comment: why don't you use firebase sdk?

Comment: Hello! I'm learning react so I didn't make a normal backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Tl;dr: Try adding '.json' to the end of the endpoint.)

I would recommend reading [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) to get a general understanding of what a CORS error is and why it might be happening.

In your case, I would recommend using the Firebase SDK that is best suited to your application. You could [start here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database) and follow the setup instructions for whichever is most applicable to your use case (perhaps the node client sdk)?

If you must avoid using the sdks for some reason then I would refer to some other Stackoverflow questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34340863/firebase-not-adding-cors-headers-to-rest-requests), which suggests that all Firebase REST endpoints need to end with '.json'.

Comment: Is there any explanation  behind your answer please?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `.json` at the end of your request and remove `.json` from `tasks.json`. like this:-

```
await fetch(
  `https://react-task-tracker-8e519-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/tasks/${id}.json`,
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const deleteHandler = async (id) => {
console.log(id);
await fetch(
  `https://react-task-tracker-8e519-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/tasks/${id}.json`,
  {
    method: "DELETE",
  }
);
```

Just replace `.json` text with `${id}.json`.

Have a nice day