# Firebase Realtime Database CORS Error While Using Angular

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database, cors

I am getting CORS error when trying to send data to Firebase Realtime Database. It only happens when I use Angular not React. I did a contact me section to get mail from anyone that wants to send message in my website so it doesn't have to be secure.

Firebase Rules:

```json
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Error when sending post request:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://pokedex-app-with-react-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/messages' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

I tried the proxy method but it didn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select data from firebase via id gives me a CORS error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67969708/select-data-from-firebase-via-id-gives-me-a-cors-error)

Answer (score 1):

The URL in the error message is missing a `.json` suffix at its end, which is required to access the REST API of the Firebase Realtime Database. So change the URL to `https://pokedex-app-with-react-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/messages.json`.

Also see:

- [Select data from firebase via id gives me a CORS error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67969708/select-data-from-firebase-via-id-gives-me-a-cors-error)