# Firebase Auth Permission Denied After Refreshing Token

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, next.js, firebase-security

I have a Firebase Realtime Database with this data

[image: Dummy data]

And the security rules

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth.uid != null",
    ".write": "auth.uid != null"
  }
}
```

In my react app, I track the current user in the application context that also uses onAuthStateChanged

```
    const [authUser, setAuthUser] = useState(null);

    ...

    const signIn = (email, password) => signInWithEmailAndPassword(firebaseAuth, email, password);

    const currUser = () => authUser;

    const authStateChange = authState => {
        if (!authState) setAuthUser(null);
        else {
            setAuthUser(authState);
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            authStateChange(user);
            setLoading(false);
        });

        return unsubscribe; // cleanup function on unmount
    }, []);

   ...
```

When a user signs in, this code runs to sign the user in with the authenticator

```
    const context = useAppContext();
    ...
    // handle form submit
    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const data = new FormData(event.currentTarget);
        context.signIn(data.get('email'), data.get('password'))
            .then(userCredential => {
                router.push('/');
            })
            .catch(err => { 
                console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
                setError({ code: err.code });
            });
    };
```

For actually accessing the database, I set up this code using axios to allow cross-origin access and using authToken params.

```
import axios from 'axios';

// create axios instance that sends to firebase rtdb 
const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_DB_URL, // firebase rtdb url
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    }
});

// all requests require params since requests will need user ID token for authorization
const params = {
    authToken: null
}

export const getUser = async (id, authToken) => {
    params.authToken = authToken;
    return instance.get(`/users/${id}.json`, {
        params: params
    });
}
```

So when I actually put this all together and just get the one test data in users/test.json, I call the function to get the current user ID token with a forced refresh, then use the axios calls

```
    import { getUser } from "../lib/firebase/rtdb";

    ...

    const context = useAppContext();
    if (context.currUser()) {
        // add user to realtime database users document
        context.currUser().getIdToken(true)
            .then(idTokenString => {
                getUser('test', idTokenString).then(res => console.log(res.data));
            })
    }
```

Even after using a fresh token, I get a permission denied error (code 401).

Am I clearly doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `access_token` instead of `authToken` ? Also `console.log(params.authToken)` right before the Axios request to ensure the token is valid would help? –

Comment: @Dharmaraj `access_token` didn't work and logging it printed `eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjQ2NDExN2FjMzk2YmM3MWM4YzU5ZmI1MTlmMDEzZTJiNWJiNmM2ZTEiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJuYW1l...` I did notice that even with the refreshIdToken being called multiple times, it prints that same token. Could that be an issue?

Comment: Just to confirm, does this work when you paste the `https://<DB_URL>/users/test.json?[TOKEN]` directly in browser?

Comment: @Dharmaraj `https://<DB_URL>/users/test.json?authToken=[TOKEN]` does not work. Also, just checked, but I was wrong about the token not refreshing, it is

Comment: @Dharmaraj yes I did and it was an unauthorized request. I am copying and pasting all URLs and tokens directly from the console log to ensure they're correct.

Comment: I just recalled I had posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68448750/firebase-realtime-rest-api-with-javascript) for similar issue where `access_token` didn't work either but the query param `?auth=TOKEN` did. Can you try this once (params.auth = theToken)?

Comment: @Dharmaraj auth worked for get. Seems to not work for PUT requests.

Comment: Just check if you still have authToken in put request...  also try restarting the next js server

Comment: @Dharmaraj restarting next.js seems to have fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The working query parameter for passing UD token is actually "auth" and not "access_token" as in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth#authenticate_with_an_id_token).